# Is there a way to bind SSMS 2012 keyboard shortcuts to a procedure in a way where I can pass the fully qualified object name?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sql-server-2012, ssms

In SSMS 2012, is there any way I can bind a keyboard shortcut (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>5</kbd>) so that I can highlight a qualified object name (e.g. `master.sys.objects`) and invoke my own procedure using that object name as the argument?

I know that this does work if I explicitly add quotes or brackets around the object name prior to using the keyboard shortcut (e.g. highlight the string `'sys.objects'`, but this becomes tedious when wanting to use my shortcut easily by directly highlighting tables in existing queries.

For more context, I noticed that <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> (the shortcut for sp_help) now supports fully-qualified object names.  For example, highlighting `sys.objects` and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> works perfectly in SSMS 2012 (it does not in SSMS 2008).  Here is the [relevant Connect issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/349116/keyboard-shortcut-alt-f1-sp-help-doesnt-work-for-tables-belonging-to-non-default-schemas) that describes this enhancement.

However, when looking at the keyboard binding for this shortcut, it looks like this action should be synonymous with invoking sp_help on the highlighted text:

[image]

This turns out not to be the case, as you can see by running the following two calls to sp_help, both of which fail with error `Incorrect syntax near '.'.`:

```
USE master
GO
EXEC sp_help sys.objects
GO
EXEC sp_help master.sys.objects
GO
```

If there is a way for me to be able to invoke my own procedures similar to the way sp_help can be invoked on qualified objects without brackets or quotes, I would love to know!

Comment: I've been wondering this for a while as well.

Answer (score 2):

SSMS 2012 supports 2 part names without quotes, for 3 part names you still need the quotes.

I still have not found any plugin that supports what you want, perhaps you could make a macro on SSMS Boost(http://www.ssmsboost.com/) to automatically add brackets, run your command then remove the brackets. I have not tried to do anything like this with it but it should be possible