# Insert a text in SSMS using a shortcut key

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

It’s mandatory in our project to add `WITH (NOLOCK)` in every `SELECT` statement.

Can someone please help me to have a shortcut key to paste/type a code fragment in SSMS?

Comment: I'd say you have to review your project rules, why do you need nolock in EVERY select statement

Comment: Adding `NOLOCK ` can hide some performance problems for queries that can be solved *usually* (!= always) by [creating indexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx) and using [SARG-able predicates](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/inside-search-arguments).

Answer (score 0):

In SSMS, own short keys and menus can be configured:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174178.aspx

So the keyboard accelerator dialog box might be a good start to look at.

Here are even more hints:

[Is there a way to bind SSMS 2012 keyboard shortcuts to a procedure in a way where I can pass the fully qualified object name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974652/is-there-a-way-to-bind-ssms-2012-keyboard-shortcuts-to-a-procedure-in-a-way-wher)

Comment: custom shortcut queries in SSMS 2016 are not being pasted as text in the current query window, but are executed in "the background" instead. So defining a text block as a custom query doesn't allow to use the shortcut to paste the text. Any other suggestion?